# How to get m_dd_yyyy format in unix as 6_19_2013 for current date

Tags: unix

Please let me know how to get `m_dd_yyyy` format in Unix.

Example: for the current date I need as `6_19_2013`

I know only

```
date +%m_%d_%Y
```

only which is giving as `06_19_2013` but I need as `6_19_2013`. I don't want `0` append before month for single month value.

Comment: Let me encourage you to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM-DD, if at all possible. Unlike M_DD_YYYY, it's standard, it's unambiguous, and it sorts properly. And you can print it with `date +%F`.

Answer (score 4):

As explained on [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) you simply have to tell date not to pad the output, by adding a `-` to the format string:

```
date +%-m_%-d_%Y
```

Just for completeness' sake the  relevant part of the manpage:

```
By default, date pads  numeric fields with zeroes.  The  following
optional flags may follow '%':

   - (hyphen) do not pad the field 
   _ (underscore) pad with spaces 0
   (zero) pad with zeros 
   ^ use upper case if possible 
   # use opposite case if possible

After  any  flags  comes     an optional field width, as a decimal number;
then an optional modifier, which is either E to use the locale's alternate
representations  if available, or O to use the locale's alternate numeric 
symbols if available.
```